# Beginner learning javascript

Tags: javascript

I am beginner in javaScript, I am trying to practice if and else statements. I have defined a function and called the function. Everything is working but i am not able to understand why I am getting "undefined" in console.log with the executed function.

```js
console.log("Starting");

function data(school) {
  if (school == 10) {
    console.log("its old");
  } else if (school <= 9) {
    console.log("its new");
  } else {
    console.log("no-data-available");
  }
}
var result = console.log(data(10));

console.log("Closing");
```

Comment: It's because you're `console.log()`-ing the return value of `data(10)`, and your function doesn't return anything, so it's logging "nothing" which is `undefined`

Comment: Try **return “it’s old”** instead of **console.log(“it’s old”)**

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to call `console.log()` on `data()`, since it calls `console.log()` on its own (and returns `undefined`, which you're seeing).

However, if you change `data()` to return the values, not log them, then you do need to call `console.log()`.

In either case, when you're assigning `var result = console.log(...)`, `result` will end up being `undefined`.

```js
function data(school) {
  if (school == 10) {
    return "its old";
  } else if (school <= 9) {
    return "its new";
  } else {
    return "no-data-available";
  }
}
var result = data(10);
console.log(result);
```

will probably do what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried your code still the console is same, executed function and undefined.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not returning anything from the function explicitly.

[Function Description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#Description)

> When a `return` statement is used in a function body, the execution of the function is stopped. If specified, a given value is returned to the function caller.
>
> If the value is omitted, `undefined` is returned instead.

Answer (score 1):

The error is occurring because your function `data()` doesn't return any value. You need to return some value if you don't want to print `undefined`.

```
function data(school) {
  if (school == 10) {
    console.log("its old");
    return 'old data';
  } else if (school <= 9) {
    console.log("its new");
    return 'new data';
  } else {
  console.log("no-data-available");
    return 'data unavailable';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your function does not have a return statement, in such cases function returns undefined value. So last line

```
console.log(data(10));
```

prints undefined.

You need to return the values from data function, if you want to print them outside.

```js
console.log("Starting");

function data(school) {
  if (school == 10) {
    return "its old";
  } else if (school <= 9) {
    return "its new";
  } else {
    return "no-data-available";
  }
}
var result = console.log(data(10));

console.log("Closing");
```

Answer (score 0):

Solve this problem

```js
console.log("Starting");

function data(school) {
  if (school == 10) {
    console.log("its old");
  } else if (school <= 9) {
    console.log("its new");
  } else {
    console.log("no-data-available");
  }
  return school;
}
var result = console.log(data(10));

console.log("Closing");
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no need of appending the function result to the variable , a function can be directly called.

```js
function data(school) {

  if (school == 10) {
    console.log("its old")

  } else if (school <= 9) {
    console.log("its new")

  } else {
    console.log("no-data-available")

  }
}
data(10);


console.log("Closing");
```

Answer (score 0):

When JavaScript reaches a return statement, the function will stop executing.

If the function was invoked from a statement, JavaScript will "return" to execute the code after the invoking statement.

Functions often compute a return value. The return value is "returned" back to the "caller":

```js
console.log("Starting");

function data(school) {
  if (school == 10) {
    return "its old";
  } else if (school <= 9) {
    return "its new";
  } else {
    return "no-data-available";
  }
}
var result = console.log(data(10));

console.log("Closing");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the shortest and cleanest.
There is not need to introduce var result.

```js
console.log("Starting");

function data(school) {
  if (school === 10) {
    return "its old";
  } else if (school <= 9) {
    return "its new";
  } else {
   return "no-data-available";
  }
}

console.log(data(10));
console.log("Closing");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return things, instead of logging them to the console.

```
console.log("Starting");

function data(school) {
  if (school == 10) {
    return "its old";
  } else if (school <= 9) {
    return "its new";
  } else {
    return "no-data-available";
 }
}
let result = data(10);
console.log(result)

console.log("Closing");
```